# how to integrate $\iiint \sin \frac yx$?

Tags: integration

The whole question is:
$$\int_0^1\int_0^{z\pi}\int_\frac{y}{\pi}^z \sin\frac{y}{x}dxdydz$$

I tried to use integration by substitution, t = y/x.
but it can't, since it is $\frac yx$, not $\frac xy$

Also, I tried to change it to cylindrical coordinate.
The problem is the range. The range of the question includes some variables. so It was hard to assume.

Is there any way to solve this integral?

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of integration?

Comment: how to change the order when the range includes variable?

Comment: Ways to change variables: $x$ goes from $0$ to $1,$ but then $y$ goes from $0$ to $\pi x,$ and $z$ goes from $x$ to $1.$ That's just one way. You can also start with $y$ going from $0$ to $\pi.$ Not sure if any will work.

Comment: Fixing $z$, your region of integration for the inner two integrals is in the rectangle $[0,z]\times[0,\pi z]$ and to the right of $y/\pi=x$. Rethinking this region, it is the triangle under $y=\pi x$. If you want to integrate over $y$ as the inner variable instead of $x$, you get $\int_0^z\int_0^{\pi x}\square\,{\rm d}y{\rm d}x$ instead of $\int_0^{\pi z}\int_{y/\pi}^z\square\,{\rm d}x{\rm d}y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we wish to compute the integral

$$I=\int_0^1\int_0^{z\pi}\int_{\frac{y}{\pi}}^z \sin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)~\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y~\mathrm{d}z.$$

We consider first the inner integral

$$J(z)=\int_0^{z\pi}\int_{\frac{y}{\pi}}^z \sin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)~\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y$$

where $z\in(0,1)$. We can write this as a double integral over some domain $\Omega_z$ depending on $z$. This domain will be given by

$$\Omega_z=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\frac{y}{\pi}<x<z\text{ and } 0<y<z\pi\right\}.$$

Now let us write this domain in a slightly different way. In particular, we can write it as

$$\Omega_z=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:0<x<z\text{ and } 0<y<x\pi\right\}$$

(I'll leave the details to you). This means that

$$J(z)=\iint_{\Omega_z}\sin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)~\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y=\int_0^z\int_0^{x\pi}\sin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)~\mathrm{d}y~\mathrm{d}x$$

where we got the integration bounds from the second expression for $\Omega_z$. But we can compute this as

$$J(z)=\int_0^z\biggl[-x\cos\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\biggr]_{y=0}^{y=x\pi}~\mathrm{d}x=-\int_0^zx(\cos\pi-\cos 0)~\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^z2x~\mathrm{d}x=z^2.$$

This means that

$$I=\int_0^1 J(z)~\mathrm{d}z=\int_0^1 z^2~\mathrm{d}z=\frac{1}{3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Change of order of integration. The integral is equivalent to $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{z}\int_{0}^{\pi x}\sin(y/x)dydxdz$. Can you continue from here?